# Inverse of Eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the physical meaning of inverse square root of the eigen value? Is it possible to use it as stretch factor to decorrelate the data.

Answer (score 1):

Given a matrix $A$, one calculates the eigenvalues of $A^TA$; the square roots of eigenvalues are the [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of $A$, $\sigma_1\ge \dots \ge \sigma_n$. They give the stretch factors of $A$ in various directions. The image of the unit ball under $A$ is an ellipsoid with semi-axes $\sigma_j$. Applying the reciprocal factors $\sigma_j^{-1}$, one can bring the shape back to the unit ball. From some angle this can be seen as removing correlations in the data. The relevant term is the [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).